# What should I fill my yard with after draining stagnant water?

Tags: drainage

First time homeowner. I don't know how to develop this area, which use to be unused overgrown space on the property until my dad cut down all the small trees so the area can be used for a garden. He built a piling over the stagnant water but a long term solution is needed.

[image]

This is a picture of our backyard, adjacent to a detention pond. I'm trying to drain the pond in photo 2, which comes from an overflow pipe from the detention pond, put in drainage (extending the overflow pipe beyond the fence), and turn it into yard space.

Had a contractor quote me $4k to put in 3/4" gravel and top it with loam. Then, I found out about the overflow pipe, called city wastewater to see if it could be capped (nope), and now the project includes extending that pipe away from the property.

I wanted to know if the pricing looks right (Salem, NH) and whether to go with the contractor.

Comment: First need to see what the city will let you do, extending the pipe or even filling the area in, hopefully they are nice about it.  3 feet deep will take quite a bit of fill, but should get three or more quotes.  Ask neighbours/friends for recommendations.  Asking about prices is not a good question for this site.

Comment: Plant a few apple trees and enjoy the orchard.

Comment: You have the basics for a great pond.

Comment: You appear to be intent on destroying what appears to be a properly designed stormwater runoff control system. You might want to make sure that you won't be required to restore it to the original state when the appropriate authorities notice what you've done.